# Running Halo: Combat Evolved on 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, wine, games, microsoft

I followed the instructions on WineHQ and got the game installed, but when I run it, it looks like this

[image]

and the whole screen occasionally flickers. Does anyone know why, and if I can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using Intel graphics and the current open source driver doesn't have what Halo demands. It works great on AMD and Nvidia hardware. I too have been trying to get Halo to work on my Intel laptop.

Comment: So there's nothing I can do about it, then?

Comment: Sadly, no. Running in safe mode makes the images render properly, but not even close to being playable.